# How to display array of string together in a textview from a JSON data array in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code sample used for update textview text, I would like to pass all string coming in an array from JSON response

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *parseURL = @"url link";
NSString *encodeurl =[parseURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeurl];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if(data){
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"Branches"];
    for (NSDictionary * dataDict in messageArray) {
        NSString *me = [dataDict objectForKey:@"branch_name"];
        txt.text = me;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ya you are execute the loop so in here you are append the last value to your textview that the reason you get last value only, in here you can implement two ways , one use tableview else use NSMutableString

Answer (score 0):

First thing You are setting `textView` text in `for loop` again and again which replace the previous text. So that you have to `append` all strings in a single string and after for loop end assign this string to `UITextView.`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normal it would show just latest string, because you're running a loop and latest object in this loop overrides the previous one

You can use `NSMutableString` before your `for` loop

```
NSMutableString *branchesString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

Then into your for loop do so

```
[branchesString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, ", [dataDict objectForKey:@"branch_name"]]];
```

after your loop, you can set this string to your textView.text

Your code would look like this

```
if(data){
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"Branches"];

    NSMutableString *branchesString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary * dataDict in messageArray) {
        [branchesString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [dataDict objectForKey:@"branch_name"]]];
    }

    txt.text = branchesString;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your for loop like this,

```
  for (NSDictionary * dataDict in messageArray) {

    NSString *me = [dataDict objectForKey:@"branch_name"];

    txt.text = [txt.text stringByAppendingString:me]; //change



    //txt.text =messageArray;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

if you want next string in new line then,

```
 txt.text = [txt.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",txt.text]];
```

If want by comma separated then,

```
 txt.text = [txt.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",txt.text]];
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

`for`/`for-each` loop is redundant. Use `componentsJoinedByString:` on your array.

```
NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"Branches"];

txt.text = [messageArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]; // linebreak between each message

// Use a space, comma, linebreak (\n), or whatever separator you prefer.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray * arrMsg = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.branch_name"];

txt.text = [arrMsg componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];  //use your saperator which you want to join the strings
```